# DTP how to view status / log?

Tags: sap-bw, data-transfer-process, request-monitor

Envrionment: SAP BW

In SAP BW I execute a DTP (Data Transfer Process). After executing the DTP a dialog pops up if I want to see the Request-Monitor.

But how to open the request monitor to view the status of a DTP other than clicking on yes of the mentioned dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to **DSO** and right click on it.
You will find **manage** tab inside that.

Click on **manage** button and you will find second tab as **Requests**. You will get list of all requests loaded on that DSO.

Click on the **Load Monitor** (6th Column from left and show you one graph like icon) of the request you are interested to monitor. And it will direct open **Request-Monitor**.